# Calculate error for monthly exchange rates

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation

I'm working on a project that will convert $USD to other currencies.  The system will use average monthly exchange rates instead of daily because of pre-existing limitations.  I need to calculate an estimate of the amount of error that will result from using monthly average.  My idea is to

1. Download historical daily exchange rates for several years
2. Calculate the monthly average for each month
3. Subtract the monthly average from each daily amount that month
4. Find the standard deviation for the differences

I would report the standard deviation as the expected error amount.  Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Apart from the point that the standard deviation is the root mean square difference rather than the mean difference, it may depend on what you are using this for.  Another point to consider is in cases where one currency moves dramatically against the other so the scales are substantially different at different times; if so, it may be better to work with relative rather than absolute errors.

Comment: Thanks Henry.  After doing a bit more research based on your comment I've decided to use the average absolute deviation.